# Finding general formula and prime factorisation

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

Let A denote the set of all positive even integers. We call a number a in A “magic" if a cannot be expressed as a product of two other members of A.

I have found a general form for this series a=4x-y, where x is an int >1 and y is of the set {1,2,3}. I was wondering if there was a better way to write this?

Also how would we go about proving that every element of A can be expressed as a product of the "magic" numbers?

Comment: If $y$ is $1$ or $3$, $a\not \in A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic numbers are all those that have only one factor of $2$ in their factorization, because when you multiply two even numbers you get two factors of $2$.  These are the numbers equivalent to $2 \bmod 4$

Any member $a$ of $A$ that is equivalent to $0 \bmod 4$ can be factored as $2\cdot \frac a2$.  Because it is a multiple of $4$, $\frac a2$ still has a factor $2$.

To prove any element of $A$ can be expressed as a product of magic numbers, factor it as $2^km$ with $m$ odd.  You can then write it as the product of $k-1\ 2$'s and $2m$, all of which are magic.

Comment: So is the general form just 2mod4? Because isn't 2mod4=2

Comment: Or (n)mod4 that is not equal to zero?

Comment: $A=\{2,4,6,8,10,12,14,\ldots \}. a$ can be any of $\{2,6,10,14,\ldots\}$  Your first comment seems confused, but it may be informal presentation.  My first paragraph says that the possibilities for $a$ are numbers equivalent to $2 \bmod 4$.  It is true that $2 \bmod 4=2$, but it is also true that $6 \bmod 4=2$.  The second is wrong, as $1 \bmod 4 =1 \neq 0$ but is not in $A$.

Comment: I said it had to be equivalent to $2 \bmod 4$, which includes $6,10,14,\ldots $  It is all the numbers of the form $4k+2$